# Download takes just too much time

Tags: android, networking

I'm trying to download a file in my app, but the download times are inconsistently too long. 
Sometimes it just downloading it in normal time, but sometimes it just stuck for like 30 seconds or more until it will just fail due to time out error.

Why would that be?

```
    private void Download(String url, String destFileName) throws IOException{
        //TODO remove that
//      File file = new File(destFileName);
//      if(file.exists())
//          return;

        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d("DownloadFile", "Downloading url: " + url + ", dest: " + destFileName);

        HttpGet httppost = null;
        AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("TvinciAndroid");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFileName);

        try {

            httppost = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse res = client.execute(httppost);

            if (res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Header[] headers = res.getHeaders("Location");
                if(headers != null && headers.length != 0) {
                    url = headers[headers.length - 1].getValue();
                    Download(url, destFileName);
                }
            }

            HttpEntity responseEntity = res.getEntity();

            if (responseEntity != null && responseEntity.getContentLength() > 0) {
                InputStream is = AndroidHttpClient.getUngzippedContent(responseEntity);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    line += "\n";
                    fos.write(line.getBytes());
                    bld.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();
                if(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    Log.d("file content", bld.toString());
                bld = null;
            }

        } 
        catch(IOException ex){
            throw ex;
        }
        finally {
            client.close();
            fos.close();
        }
    }
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: This is called from an asynctask

Comment: You shouldn't be reading lines unless you know the file consists of lines of text: you should be reading byte arrays. And you shouldn't be using string concatenation. Possibly that's where the time is going.

Answer (score -1):

Try specifying the buffer to 8192.

```
//input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
```

I have a sample working code here that can download a file via URL It is different from your implementation, but this might help you.

```
try {

        URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        // getting file length
        int lengthOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

        // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

        // Output stream to write file
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;

        pDialog.setMax(lengthOfFile);
        NOTIFICATION_ID = 1+lengthOfFile;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {

            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
            //publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
            publishProgress(""+(int)(total));
            notifBuilder.setProgress(lengthOfFile, (int)(total), false)
                        .setContentText("Download in progress... "+total+"/"+lengthOfFile);
            nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notifBuilder.build());

            // writing data to file
            output.write(data, 0, count);

        }

        // flushing output
        output.flush();

        // closing streams
        output.close();
        input.close();

    }  catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return e.getMessage()+" download failed!";
    }
```

I Hope this helps.

Comment: Your code doesn't handle redirects which I must have. But i'll try to set the buffer my self and report back. Thank you

Comment: Well, I tried setting the buffer size to 8192 as you suggested, but still no difference

Comment: 8192 is the default buffer size for BufferedInputStream. It won't make any difference specifying it or leaving it out. And if you're  reading into a byte array the buffered stream is superfluous anyway.